# Summing up all Attributes Neo4j

Tags: performance, neo4j, path

I'm here to ask you help. 
I have a neo4j database with complete k-ary trees, with millions of nodes. Both Nodes and Edges have a constant number of attributes (may vary from Nodes to Edges but all Nodes have EXACTLY x attributes and all Edges have y attributes).
My task is to return the sum of all attributes on both nodes and edge. I tried this query:

```
Match p=(:Vertex_ss3 {name:'vertex_1594320'})-[:EDGE_ss3*]->(:Vertex_ss3 {name:'vertex_1'}) 
return 
reduce(sum = 0, n IN nodes(p) | sum + n.attr1) as tot_attr1_node,
reduce(sum = 0, n IN nodes(p) | sum + n.attr2) as tot_attr2_node, 
reduce(sum = 0, n IN nodes(p) | sum + n.attr3) as tot_attr3_node,
reduce(sum = 0, n IN nodes(p) | sum + n.attr4) as tot_attr4_node, 
reduce(sum = 0, n IN nodes(p) | sum + n.attr5) as tot_attr5_node,
reduce(sum = 0, n IN nodes(p) | sum + n.attr6) as tot_attr6_node,
reduce(sum = 0, n IN relationships(p) | sum + n.attr1) as tot_attr1_edge,
reduce(sum = 0, n IN relationships(p) | sum + n.attr2) as tot_attr2_edge,
reduce(sum = 0, n IN relationships(p) | sum + n.attr3) as tot_attr3_edge,
reduce(sum = 0, n IN relationships(p) | sum + n.attr4) as tot_attr4_edge,
reduce(sum = 0, n IN relationships(p) | sum + n.attr5) as tot_attr5_edge
```

It takes about 13/14 seconds to return with a 3-ary Tree with a depth of 13. Is there a way to get an improvement in terms of time?

I don't really know how nodes(p) and relationships(p) works, but as I wrote the query it seems that for each attribute, the DB has to retrive all nodes or all relationships from the path, isn't there a way to do it once for all?

Thanks in advice :)

Comment: You can use `WITH nodes(p) as n, relationships(p) as rels` to retrieve the list of nodes and relationships once, then reference those variables in your sums.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Not sure if this will be faster or slower, but you could try unwinding nodes and relationships, then using the SUM() function to get the values you want.

```
MATCH p=(:Vertex_ss3 {name:'vertex_1594320'})-[:EDGE_ss3*]->(:Vertex_ss3 {name:'vertex_1'}) 
WITH p
UNWIND nodes(p) as n
WITH p, 
SUM(n.attr1) as tot_attr1_node
SUM(n.attr2) as tot_attr2_node
SUM(n.attr3) as tot_attr3_node
SUM(n.attr4) as tot_attr4_node
SUM(n.attr5) as tot_attr5_node
SUM(n.attr6) as tot_attr6_node
UNWIND relationships(p) as n
WITH p, tot_attr1_node, tot_attr2_node, tot_attr3_node, tot_attr4_node, tot_attr5_node, tot_attr6_node
SUM(n.attr1) as tot_attr1_edge
SUM(n.attr2) as tot_attr2_edge
SUM(n.attr3) as tot_attr3_edge
SUM(n.attr4) as tot_attr4_edge
SUM(n.attr5) as tot_attr5_edge
RETURN tot_attr1_node, 
tot_attr2_node, 
tot_attr3_node, 
tot_attr4_node, 
tot_attr5_node, 
tot_attr6_node, 
tot_attr1_edge, 
tot_attr2_edge, 
tot_attr3_edge, 
tot_attr4_edge, 
tot_attr5_edge
```

Comment: Looks like you accepted this one. Does this mean you saw a noticeable increase in query speed? As I'm a bit fuzzy myself on the performance of using UNWIND and various functions vs using REDUCE, I'm curious how this worked out.

Answer (score 3):

You should be able to use one of the [APOC procedures](https://neo4j-contrib.github.io/neo4j-apoc-procedures) that can execute a query (with varying data) in parallel. Unfortunately, they are poorly documented (and some not at all). So, I will provide a semi-tutorial on one of the procedures and how it can help you to get faster results.

The query below is how you can use [apoc.cypher.mapParallel](https://neo4j-contrib.github.io/neo4j-apoc-procedures/#_cypher_execution) to sum every node attribute in parallel (at least potentially; the procedure determines the actual degree of parallelism), followed by summing every relationship attribute in parallel.

```
MATCH p=(:Vertex_ss3 {name:'vertex_1594320'})-[:EDGE_ss3*]->(:Vertex_ss3 {name:'vertex_1'}) 
CALL apoc.cypher.mapParallel(
  'UNWIND nodes AS n RETURN _ AS attr, SUM(n[_]) AS sum',
  {nodes: NODES(p)},
  ['attr1','attr2','attr3','attr4','attr5','attr6']) YIELD value AS nodeAttr
WITH p, COLLECT(nodeAttr) AS nodeAttrs
CALL apoc.cypher.mapParallel(
  'UNWIND rels AS n RETURN _ AS attr, SUM(n[_]) AS sum',
  {rels: RELATIONSHIPS(p)},
  ['attr1','attr2','attr3','attr4','attr5']) YIELD value AS relAttr
RETURN nodeAttrs, COLLECT(relAttr) AS relAttrs;
```

- The first argument to the procedure is the Cypher query you want to run in parallel.
- The second argument to the procedure defines the parameters to the Cypher query passed to the procedure. For each parameter, the procedure creates an identifier with the same name (e.g., the value of "{foo}" can be accessed just by using the `foo` identifier).
- The procedure ensures that the underscore ("_") identifier will have the value of one of the elements in the list (the last argument) passed to the procedure.
- `nodeAttrs` and `relAttrs` will be collections of {attr: ..., sum: ...} maps.

Comment: Thanks... Is this available also for the creation? I was searching for a faster creation than the Load CSV with periodic commit... Something similiar the Batch-parallel-import that was on Neo4j 2.2, if I'm not wrong

Comment: Good amendment to the really poor documentation!